# Cannot apply one hypothesis to another

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I am very new to Coq and I'm trying to prove that if two functions are injectives, the composition of theses two functions is also injective.
Here is my code:

```
Definition compose {A B C} (g: B -> C) (f: A -> B) :=
  fun x : A => g (f x).

Definition injective {A B} (f: A -> B) :=
  forall x1 x2, f x1 = f x2 -> x1 = x2.

(*
Definition surjective {A B} (f: A -> B) :=
  forall y: B, exists x: A, f x = y.
*)

Theorem example {A B C} (g: B -> C) (f: A -> B) :
  injective f /\ injective g -> injective (compose g f).
Proof.
  intros.
  destruct H as (H1,H2).
  cut (forall x1 x2: A, (compose g f) x1 = (compose g f) x2).
  intros.
  unfold compose in H.
  unfold injective in H2.
```

The result is:

```
2 goals
A : Type
B : Type
C : Type
g : B -> C
f : A -> B
H1 : injective f
H2 : forall x1 x2 : B, g x1 = g x2 -> x1 = x2
H : forall x1 x2 : A, g (f x1) = g (f x2)
______________________________________(1/2)
injective (compose g f)
______________________________________(2/2)
forall x1 x2 : A, compose g f x1 = compose g f x2
```

From this state, I am trying to apply `H2` in `H` in order to prove that `f(x1)=f(x2)`. I have tried the `apply` tactic as well as the `specialized` tactic but none of them worked.

Here is the actual proof I am following :

[image]

EDIT:
Thank you very much for you help! This code works now :

```
Theorem compose_injective {A B C} (g: B -> C) (f: A -> B) :
  injective f /\ injective g -> injective (compose g f).
Proof.
  intros.
  destruct H as (H1,H2).
  unfold injective.
  intros.
  unfold injective in H2.
  apply H2 in H.
  unfold injective in H1.
  apply H1 in H.
  exact H.
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `cut`, use `unfold injective.` to reveal the hypothesis `compose g f x = compose g f x'`.

Answer (score 0):

`apply H2 in H` says you're missing an `x1` and `x2`. First get yourself an `x1` and `x2` by `unfold`ing `injective` in your goal and using `intros`. Then you can `apply H2` (with appropriate parameters) `in H1`.